# value from HTML textbox to Javascript var

Tags: javascript

Hi want to store what user input into the textbox into my javascript var to be passed to my external PHP page,

I can pass the variable if i just define a value like mySite= 22 but not from what user enters into the text box.

Please help me to get access to the texbox.value

```
  <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="submitFun(this)">
  <input type="text" name="order_IDsearch" id="order_IDsearch"onBlur="javascript:setmysite(this);">

    <input type="submit" />

     </form> 



  <script type="text/javascript">


   var mySite = '';
   function setmysite(v1) {

   var parent = document.getElementById('list');
   var element = parent.GetElementsByTagName('order_IDsearch')[0];

   mySite = element;


   }

   function submitFun(f1) {

   t = './get_order.php?s=' + mySite;
   t = encodeURI (t);
   f1.action = t; 
   f1.submit();
   return true;
   }
```

Comment: have you tried `document.getElementById('order_IDsearch').value`, or if using jQuery `$('order_IDsearch').val()` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try document.getElementById('order_IDsearch').value;

Comment: It works now, Thank you I have made a stupid mistake, I have define the var out side of the function();